# What is the best way to check to see which keys in a set exist in another sorted set with Redis

Tags: redis

Suppose I have a set of online users, containing perhaps 20,000 entries.

Next, imagine that each user has their own sorted set of people that they are following.

When a user logs in I would like to check to see which users in their following lists are online.

There are two options as far as I can see.

```
MULTI
ZINTERSTORE temp 2 online, following
ZRANGE temp 0 -1
DEL temp
MULTI EXEC
```

Alternatively, I could get the list users following list, then loop through them all, firing an ISMEMBER call for each one:

```
    SMEMBERS following


   MULTI
   foreach(following as fol){
      ISMEMBER online fol
   }
  MULTI EXEC
```

Neither approach really sits right with me.  Is there a better way?  If not which of the above would be most per formant if we imagine an average user to have 200 people in their following list, with an average online count of 20,000.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a hash for each user? Wouldn't it be simpler to add an "online" property to the user hash and check it then?

Comment: I don't, but i'm in the process of working out the best data structure to use for this app so am definitely open to changing to hashes. So what you're saying is that I am better off creating a persistent hash for each user. When a user logins in, set the users online property to true.  Then when another user logs in, pull this users sorted set of users they are following and pipeline multiple hget commands for each user in the sorted set to check the online properties of each? If you could extrapolate that into an answer, I will potentially mark it as correct.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redis documentation helps with right understanding of your question solutions.

Look at first solution with [`ZINTERSTORE`](http://redis.io/commands/zinterstore) it`s require time complexity: **O(N * K) + O(M * log(M))** in worst case with N being the smallest input sorted set, K being the number of input sorted sets and M being the number of elements in the resulting sorted set. This will be critical when you need to compare people say with 20,000 followers versus average online count of 20,000.

Your second solution is much better. Based on [ISMEMBER](http://redis.io/commands/sismember) (**O(1)**) it`s require time complexity **O(N)** in worst case with N being the smallest input set.

There is more one interesting solution about user online handling. You should know about [`SETBIT`](http://redis.io/commands/setbit) and [`GETBIT`](http://redis.io/commands/getbit) - it can handle up to 2^32 bits or users if your users has regular ids. For example - user with id 1 - 1st bit, 345 - the 345th bit and so on. In this case you have just 512mb of memory for max 4,294,967,296 users and **O(1)** time complexity to get/set they status. And using your second approach to intersect your sorted set of followers with online data.

If using redis >= 2.6 you should try to use LUA for optimize second type solution. For example `map/reduce` for 200,000 keys foreach on my laptop takes just ~720ms. And less then 
1ms for set of 200 users.

Comment: Fantastic answer...  Thank you ever so much for explaining in that level of detail.

Comment: Just thought i'd let you know that i'm now using your getbit method and its perfect in every way.  I can now store the online status of 42 billion users (if I had them) in 512mb of memory.  I did have to create a hash of string based userids to integer based ones but by sharding the users hash into 1000 item buckets and and ensuring they are all ziplisted this hash is trivial memory wise (16mb for 1 million users) and best of all, lookups are still 0(1) Thanks :)